# AWS SNS Push Notification using Laravel

Tags: laravel, push-notification, amazon-sns

I have searched AWS documentation and wasted a couple of hours but could not find the code to send push notifications using Laravel 8. Can anybody help in sending AWS SNS push notifications using Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution

first need to add this composer package

```
"aws/aws-sdk-php"
```

The code for generate endpoint ARN

```
$platformApplicationArn = config('services.sns.android_arn');

$client = new SnsClient([
        'version'     => '2010-03-31',
        'region'      => config('services.sns.region'),
        'credentials' => new Credentials(
            config('services.sns.key'),
            config('services.sns.secret')
        ),
    ]);

    $result = $client->createPlatformEndpoint(array(
        'PlatformApplicationArn' => $platformApplicationArn,
        'Token'                  => $deviceToken,
    ));

    $endPointArn = isset($result['EndpointArn']) ? $result['EndpointArn'] : '';
```

The code for send push notification

```
    $client = new SnsClient([
            'version'     => '2010-03-31',
            'region'      => config('services.sns.region'),
            'credentials' => new Credentials(
                config('services.sns.key'),
                config('services.sns.secret')
            ),
        ]);

    $fcmPayload = json_encode(
            [
                'notification' => 
                    [
                        'title' => 'Test Notification',
                        'body'  => 'Hi from RB',
                        'sound' => 'default',
                    ],
            ]
        );

    $message = json_encode(['GCM' => $fcmPayload]);

    $client->publish([
          'TargetArn'        => $userDeviceToken->endpoint_arn,
          'Message'          => $message,
          'MessageStructure' => 'json',
    ]);
```